# Displaying the Messages window from SQL Server Management Studio on a Windows Form Application in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have written a small program that will assist me in running simple database tasks (look-ups etc...). Is it possible to display the Messages window from SQL Server Management Studio programmatically using C# on a Windows Form Application? (Possibly in a messagebox or a listview)

By this I mean:

[image]

Comment: why don't you get the error message from the `SqlException` Class and if you have some code that's wrapped around a `try{}catch(SqlException sqlEx){
}` then you could capture / log and or display in a RichTextBox the `sqlEx.Message` along with the `string.Format` command to format the text..

Comment: I see what you are saying but I was looking for more of a catch all not only to show errors but to also show if a command was successful and what was affected.